# ES 5.4 - Nested Query and empty result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm starting to use ES and I struggle with the concept of nested queries. 
I would like to filter nested comment of my blog post respecting the following condition

- Only nested elements which respect query are returned
- If there are no nested results, the parent must be returned.

The goal is to return all posts without their unvalidated comments.

**My mapping**

```
GET _mapping


{  
   "post":{  
      "mappings":{  
         "post":{  
            "properties":{  
               "id":{  
                  "type":"integer"
               },
               "comments":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "include_in_parent":true,
                  "properties":{  
                     "content":{  
                        "type":"text"
                     },
                     "is_valid":{  
                        "type":"integer",
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Current documents**

```
GET _search


{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_type": "post",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "1",
        "_source": {
          "id": "1",
          "comments": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
              "is_valid" : 1
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
              "is_valid" : 0
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "comments": [
            {
              "id": "3",
              "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
              "is_valid" : 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Current query**

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments",
            "query": {
                 "match" : { "comments.is_valid" : 1 }

            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "comments"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So with this query, I can retrieve **post#1** without invalid comments in his *inner_hits* field and **post#3** cause he has no comments.

But I don't know how to get **post#2**, he has only one invalid comment and this query doesn't match.

**How would you fix this ?**

Thanks :)